# Cython error: Undeclared name not built in:array

Tags: numpy, cython, sage

I am compiling this Cython code in [Sage Cell Server](http://aleph.sagemath.org/?q=e1eea19a-d71f-48c8-94ed-3a69d5de2a38) and I get the following error.

```
undeclared name not builtin: array
```

It displays the same error in Sage Notebook. I think it is not recognizing numpy `array` but it 
 is strange cause I have imported numpy already.

```
 cython('''
  cimport numpy as np
  ctypedef np.int DTYPE
  def computeDetCy(np.ndarray[DTYPE, ndim=2] matrix):      
      return determ(matrix,len(matrix))

cdef inline int determ(np.ndarray[DTYPE, ndim=2] matrix, int n):
cdef int det = 0
cdef int p=0
cdef int h
cdef int k
cdef int i=0
cdef int j=0
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE, ndim=2] temp=np.zeros(4,4)
if n == 1:
    return matrix[0][0]
elif  n == 2:
    return matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0]
else:
    for p in range(0, n):
        h = 0
        k = 0
        for i in range(1, n):
            for j in range(0, n):
                if j==p:
                    continue 
                temp[h][k] = matrix[i][j]
                k+=1
                if k ==(n-1):
                    h+=1
                    k=0
        det= det + matrix[0][p] * (-1)**p * determ(temp, n-1)

    return det

computeDetCy(array([[13,42,43,22],[12,67,45,98],[23,91,18,54],[34,56,82,76]]))

''')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, but you imported it as `np`, not importing `*` (which would be a bad idea anyway) and didn't do a regular Python import.  (Sometimes you have to do both a `cimport` and `import`, see [this SO question for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799977/numpy-vs-cython-speed).)

However, even after

```
import numpy as np
```

and using `np.array`, I still get some errors

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'DTYPE' but got 'long'
```

So this solves your question, but isn't the whole story, and the things I tried didn't work to fix this new issue.

Comment: Your answer fixes the problem reported.  The second problem should be fixed by changing the definition of `DTYPE` to `ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE` (i.e. replace `np.int` with `np.int_t` in the `ctypedef`).